# set value of radcombobox from another combobox

Tags: telerik, rad

set value of radcombobox2 from another radcombobox1 
radcombobox2 is on asp usercontrol & radcombobox1 is on aspx page.
and value is coming from database on time of binding like this

```
 if (result.IsSuccessful)
                {
                    var rcbRadComboBox = (RadComboBox)RadGrid1.MasterTableView.FindControl("RadComboBox1");
                    if (comboEditAccessGroup != null)
                    {

                        comboEditAccessGroup.DataSource = result.Result;
                        comboEditAccessGroup.DataTextField = "Title";
                        comboEditAccessGroup.DataValueField = "JobId";
                        comboEditAccessGroup.DataBind();


                    }
                }
```

but the problem is that ,i am not able to change selected index which is selected on radcombobox1

I have used

```
 var selectedindexforjob = Request.QueryString["JobId"];
    rcbRadComboBox.SelectedValue = selectedindexforjob;
```

for achieve goal but got failure nothing happens.
please help me.
Radcombobox1====is on aspx page
Radcombobox2=====is on ascx page

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to the user control:

```
public string ComboSelectedValue
{
   get { return RadComboBox2.SelectedValue; }
   set { RadComboBox2.SelectedValue = value; }
}
```

And then you can use this property from the page:

```
MyUserControl.ComboSelectedValue = RadComboBox1.SelectedValue;
```